# "name S_ISREG is not defined" in Python

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to get a list of items in a path and identify whether it is a file or a folder.

I am running the script in Windows.

```
sftp = sftp_connection(host, username, password, INPUT_DIR)
files = get_list_directories(sftp)
if len(files) > 0:
    for file in files:
        mode = file.st_mode
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            print(file.filename + " is folder.")
        elif S_ISREG(mode):
            print(file.filename + " is file.")
```

This gives me the list of items but also outputs

> name 'S_ISDIR' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`S_ISDIR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISDIR) and [`S_ISREG`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISREG) are defined in [Python `stat` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html).

```
from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
```